# Using SetaPdf- Signer with laravel

Tags: pdf, laravel-4

I am using WKHTMLTOPDF to generate PDF and want to use [SetaPDF-Signer](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/details/) to sign the PDF.

The app is build using Laravel 4.0 framework, can someone help me with integrating this with laravel ?

Currently there is no bundle available for it i packagist.org.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

In the last days we investigate to setup a repository for Composer. It's almost finished and you're welcome to try things out!

First of all you will need to add our repository to your composer.json file:

```
"repositories" : [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://www.setasign.com/downloads/"
    }
]
```

Then you can add the evaluation package to your "require"-key. Depending on the PHP/Ioncube-Loader-Version choose a specifc version:

```
"require": {
    "setasign/eval/setapdf-signer/ioncube/php5.3": "2.*"
},
```

or

```
"require": {
    "setasign/eval/setapdf-signer/ioncube/php5.4": "2.*"
},
```

The package will automatically install the desired evaluation license as well. Just authenticate with your credetials that you'd used to register at our website.

Best regards,
Jan